# how to add big space

Tags: php, html

```
      <?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <li class="<?php print $classes[$id]; ?>"><?php print $row; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

the above code is used to output an article list. now i want to add big space after the lines which is the multiple of 10.namely,add a big space (eg:margin-bottom:30px,only to after  every 10 bullet points but the space between other li is 15px )after every 10 bullet points. how to change the above code. then i can use css to get that.
 –

Comment: What do you mean by 'big space'? Perhaps you mean a linebreak? (`<br/>`)?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to add a big space after every 10 bullet points?

Comment: no,eg:30px, but the space between other <li> is 20px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't have a clue what you mean by 'big space', *I assume you want to place an arbitry HTML tag after every 10th list item*. You can do this like so, for example:

```
 <?php $i = 0; ?>
 <?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
     <li class="<?php print $classes[$id]; ?>"><?php print $row; ?></li>
     <?php if ($i++ === 10): ?><br /><?php $i = 0; endif; ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**EDIT, *you clarified*:**

> no,eg:30px, but the space between other `<li>` is 20px.

Which can be done like so:

```
 <?php $i = 1; ?>
 <?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
     <?php $i++; ?>
     <li style="margin-bottom:<?php echo ($i === 10) ? : '30' : '20'); ?>px;" class="<?php print $classes[$id]; ?>"><?php print $row; ?></li>
     <?php if ($i === 10) $i = 1; ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I think you mean margin-bottom not margin-left.

Comment: Nope, I meant margin left. He mentions 'big space' which, I assume, implies he is floating the list items or displaying them inline. OP now clarified it's margin-bottom, so editing it anyway.

Comment: <?php $i = 0; endif; ?>  i can't understand this line well. why it shoud use $i=0.

Comment: Since you are not using the modulus operator, you have to reset the counter to 0 every time it hits 10.

Answer (score 1):

The modulus operator (%) is ideal for this:

```
<?php $i = 0; foreach ( $rows as $id => $row ): ?>
<li style="margin-bottom: <?php echo $i ++ % 10 ? '30' : '20' ?>px;" class="<?php echo $classes[$id] ?>">
    <?php echo $row ?>
</li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a slight amendment to Aron's code, if you wanted to use CSS to style the `<li>`:

```
 <?php $i = 1;
 foreach ($rows as $id => $row):
     if($i === 10){
         $end_class = ' end-class';
         $i = 1;
     } else {
         $end_class = '';
         $i++;
     }
     echo '<li class="' . $classes[$id] . $end_class . '">' . $row . '</li>';
 endforeach;
 ?>
```

You can then apply the style to `.end-class`.